# WearOS WatchFaceKotlin new AndroidX libraries

Tags: android, wear-os, androidx, watchface

I had a look at the new way of creating watchfaces for Wear OS.
https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/main/WatchFaceKotlin

In my case I do not know beforehand how many complications a watch face will have, in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/watchface/ComplicationSlotsManager) it says that dynamic creation of complications is not possible. But you should be able to disable and enable complications with [ComplicationSlotsUserStyleSetting](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/watchface/style/UserStyleSetting.ComplicationSlotsUserStyleSetting).

There is hardly any understandable documentation about this. How would that work?

I tried by setting a userStyle, but it does not seem to influence the .enabled property of a Complication in the ComplicationSlotManager.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, not an expert on watchfaces, but I think the sample here shows using that option.  https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:wear/watchface/watchface/samples/src/main/java/androidx/wear/watchface/samples/ExampleCanvasAnalogWatchFaceService.kt;l=184

Comment: Ah thanks, that does help. What is not clear to me though is if it is possible to enable/disable a ComplicationOverlay dynamically. In this example this parameter (.enabled) is set when the userStyleScheme is created. But I want to enable/disable complications dynamically based on the watch face which is currently used (note that my app is a watch face designer, so it is not known beforehand what it will look like). I can create my own enabled/disabled property, but that would mean that I have many (70 or so) ComplicationSlots active at the same time which might influence battery life? Thanks